# JavaScript: Can I declare variables inside switch cases?

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement, case, declare

In C language, you cannot declare any variables inside 'case' statements.

```
switch ( i ){
case 1:
  int a = 1; //error!
  break;
}
```

However, you can when you use with curly parentheses.

```
switch ( i ){
case 1:
  {// create another scope.
    int a = 1; //this is OK.
  }
  break;
}
```

In Javascript case, can I use var directly inside case statements?

```
switch ( i ){
case 1:
  var a = 1
  break
}
```

It seems that there is no error but I'm not confident this is grammatically OK.

Comment: Simple answer is __Yes__

Comment: javascript es5 only has function scope, `a` will be local to the function, not to the switch

Comment: @Hacketo So, Javascript can only have scopes within the global and functions?

Comment: @PRIX using `var`, yes. you can see many examples in the linked post

Comment: @Hacketo Wow, very useful link! Thank you!

Comment: @satpal agreed yes you can but it's not really good practice, they get hoisted so better to declare earlier and make sure they don't break or redeclare or even predeclare anything imho

Comment: Note that you cannot declare the same variable in different `case`s [because there is only one underlying block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes in javascript you can do this but I think testing it would be much simpler:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashkanvb/zu2ytwdj/)

```
var i = 1;
switch ( i ){
case 1:
  var a = 1;
  alert(a);
  break;
}
```